# Extend the fire propagation limit in Far Cry 2?

Tags: mods, far-cry-2

For a game that boasts the "most realistic fire" ever in a video-game (*at least when it came out, not too sure about more recent developments)* Far Cry 2's fire seems to die out way before a real fire would, especially in the dry savannah's of a war-torn African country. They should spread like ***wildfire***. Literally.

Obviously this is more of a limit imposed by the (most likely) taxing propagation algorithms, and the added rendering of those high-def textures.

**But is there a way to tweak the limit of fire spread?** Obviously not in-game, but perhaps a config file or even a mod that increases how far a fire spreads before dying out?